# django ModelForms and normal form in POST request

Tags: python, django

Hi i just have a small doubt can we create a HTML template which will have the Django form and normal HTML form together. 
I created a HTML template which has both normal HTML input tag and Django forms.

I am getting the following error when i do a form.save(commit=False)

> could not be created because the data didn't validate.

My view.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form_value = request.POST.copy()
        print form_value
        form = InfoForm(data=request.POST)
        post_val = form.save(commit=False)
```

my HTML

```
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                {{form.name}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                {{form.number}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                {{form.location}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Feedback">Feedback</label>
            <div id="Feedback" class="optionBox1">
                <div class="input-group my-add-div">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="feedback" required>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="feedback" required>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="feedback" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

my form.py

```
class InfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Project Name',max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Click to enter text',}))
    number = forms.DecimalField(label='Project #',widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter the ID',}))
    location = forms.CharField(label='Location',max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter the Location',}))
    class Meta:
       model = Info
       field = ('name','number','location',)
```

My Model.py

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True , null=True)
number = models.IntegerField(blank=True , null=True)
location = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True , null=True)
feedback = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first call `form.is_valid()` to use `save` method on the form.

Comment: it return me False, But i need to know whats wrong with my form, I guess i didnt make any mistake.

Comment: Use `form.errors` field to check the errors after `form.is_valid` method call.

Comment: Thanks i figured out the issue using form.errors and fixed it

Answer (score 3):

All what you need to create any form in template you want, example:

``

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="first_name">
    <p><input type='submit' value="Change"></p>
</form> ``
```

then, in your view call

```
first_name = request.POST['first_name']
```

and it will be works fine.